# How can I use NotifyDataSetChenged to work Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My activity only loads fragments once. After turning app off and on again list is empty. But I can see in logs that everytime i send request to server I receive answer, but it is not loading to view.

I am just starting with Kotlin so I am sorry if this problem is kind of silly...

```
class ItemsFragmentCp : Fragment(), ItemCellClickListener {
    private val itemsList = ArrayList<ItemModel>()
    private lateinit var itemsAdapter: ItemsAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)
        itemsAdapter = ItemsAdapter(itemsList, this)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        var recyclerView = itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context);
        recyclerView.adapter = ItemsAdapter(itemsList, this);
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(
            recyclerView.context,
            layoutManager.orientation
        )
        val activity = getActivity();
        val intent = activity?.getIntent();
        val settingsJson = intent?.getStringExtra("settingsJson").toString()
        val settingsData = SettingsLoaderMyCompany(settingsJson)

        settingsData.getSettings().getEmails().forEach {
            val har = MyCompanyApiRepo();
            val sign = har.makeSign();
            prepareListData(it.getEmail(), sign)
        }

    }

    private fun prepareListData(email :String, sign :String) {
        val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(MyCompanyApiEndpoints::class.java)
        val call = request.getItems(email, sign)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<MyCompanyGetItemsList> {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyCompanyGetItemsList>, response: Response<MyCompanyGetItemsList>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val serverResponse : MyCompanyGetItemsList = response.body()!!;
                    serverResponse.items.forEach {
                        val item = ItemModel(it.id, it.name, it.datetime)
                        itemsList.add(item)
                    }

                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    Log.d("Error", response.toString())
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyCompanyGetItemsList>, t: Throwable) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: guess I somewhat get your idea, imho notifyItemChanged wont help you at this case, because you are not observing for change on `itemList` hence you are getting the value which would only called once the view is created so in this case you need to look on something called livedata, stateflow, using viewmodel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel or tigged addFunction inside your adapter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by turning app on and off, but I am assuming you are either killing the app or it is dormant. In either case notifydatasetchanged is no longer ideal and hence causes issues. best would be  to reload the data by Overridng OnResume functionality and calling the prepareListdata function, everytime on load.

Ideal situation would be to monitor the data using LiveData, Flow, etc which results in automatic updates...